# How to Extract Elements?

Tags: programming

I could not find the right answer on the following question:

If we have finite vector `(a_{1},a_{2},...,a_{n})`, how to extract any element from it, for example `a_{5}`?

To say more clearly, I need an analog of list in mathematica, where we have list={1,5,8,6,9} and list[3]=8, list[5]=9.

The vector is a math term to express that one object has many different info in it.

for example take a code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \A {(1,1)};
\draw \A -- (8,8);
\gettikzxy{\A}{\ax}{\ay}
\def \A {(1,1)};
\draw (\ax+10cm,\ay-5) -- (8,8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It "extracts coordinates from A point" and lets me to manipulate with them, but I need more generalized form, to work on more "elements".

Comment: Do you mean the bunch of tokens `a_{5}`?

Comment: Please, add some more details. As it stands the question is very unclear.

Comment: On the forum is questions about: "Extract x, y coordinate of an arbitrary point in TikZ". I would like to extract any element from any finite vector.

Comment: tex does not have vectors, that is just the typeset text for some subscripted letters and commas, there is no underlying object from which to extract anything. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Please make your questions specific to a specific tex question, show the input (preferably a complete document from `\documentclass` to `\end{document}` and state what output you hope to get from that input.

Comment: Vector, element, object is only used to say that I have \def \g {(x,y,z)}, now later I need to use y, how can I get it. for example it is needed to find middle point on a line and many other.

Comment: As far as tex is concerned you just have a sequence of letters `(`, `x`, `,`, .... there are macros to split things up on commas  (as used in `\documentclass` options for example) although the `(` makes using those much more difficult as the first value would be `(x`  but your question is still far to vague you should ask about a specific case, as there is no general answer.

Comment: In particular you mention lines, if your question is about tikz lines for example, ask about _that_ as the way tikz stores coordinates is very different from the way say pstricks or xypic or picture environment store coordinates.

Comment: If the 'vector' is a list, then the list tools from `etoolbox` provide some clue

Comment: I guess that the OP wants to have some tool like in *Mathematica*, for example, to print the `5th` entry of the `list`, with `list[5]`, for example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I think Sigur is right. I think this is a duplicate of a question you had already answer it about the largest value and it's position in a list. I can not find it now.

Comment: This sound like a job for [`l3seq`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/l3kernel/interface3.pdf).

Comment: You make a list via double braces `\def\zz{{1,2,3,4}}`. Then access the elements via first executing the caller `\pgfmathparse{\zz[3]}` and then using the result that is kept in the macro `\pgfmathresult`. Mathematica and other CAS are a different breed, you will quickly see that you need to change your view on TeX programming. Feature X in Y probably won't exist in TeX and you have to morph into a different type of programming. Macro expansion is completely different than typed languages.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the `listofitems` package does, even using the syntax you requested.  The list separator can also be changed (default comma).  The elements of the list, such as `\mylist[4]`, are fully expandable (two expansions will retrieve the tokens of the list element).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\begin{document}
\readlist\mylist{1,5,8,6,9}
The third element is \mylist[3] and the 5th element is \mylist[5].
\end{document}
```

[image]